# Converting a number with dot and comma to double will fail

Tags: c#, parsing, decimal

having a string that's looking like "1.900,00". How could I format this string to a decimal of 1900?

Using:

```
decimal.TryParse("1.900,00", out var vkp)
```

Will give me a false result. How can I handle this?

Here's a URL to the online C# compiler: https://dotnetfiddle.net/B5EyyC

Comment: `NumberStyles.AllowThousands`

Comment: @CodeCaster I have tried: 
decimal.TryParse("1.900,00", NumberStyles.AllowThousands, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out value1);
Doesn't work.

Comment: The invariant culture uses `,` as a thousands-separator and `.` as the separator between the whole number and the fractional part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using a `CultureInfo` that uses `'.'` as thousands separator and `','` as decimal separator (for example `"de-DE"`). And also the appropriate `NumberStyles`.

```
string input = "1.900,00";
decimal.TryParse(input, 
    NumberStyles.AllowThousands | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, 
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), out var output);
```

You can even create your very own instance of [NumberFormatInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo) where you can specify the `NumberDecimalSeparator` and `NumberGroupSeparator` any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
        string s = "1.900,00";
        s = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(",")).Replace(".", "") + "." + s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(",") + 1);
        decimal vkp = 0;
        decimal.TryParse(s, out vkp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try the following:

```
string number = "1.900,00";
decimal.TryParse(number.Split(",")[0].Replace(".",""), out var vkp);
```

In case you need a more foolproof checking you could try making a function that checks whether or not the string contains a ',' character.

```
public static bool ToDouble(string s, out double d)
{
   if (s.Contains(","))
      return double.TryParse(s.Split(",")[0].Replace(".", ""), out d);

   return double.TryParse(s, out d);
}
```

Also you can get the decimal separator of you localization settings via:

```
string dsep = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator
```

Answer (score 0):

[Decimal.TryParse doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
//using System.Globalization;   
NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands;
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES");               
Decimal vkp;        
Decimal.TryParse("1.900,00", style, culture, out vkp);
```